# UITesting Citrix Application with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests, citrix, uitest

I´m trying to make a UITest with visual Studio 2015 in a Citrix Application. My test inserts text and press return key, TAB key and others. After correctly sending in text, the enter is not being sent. I tried it with:

```
 InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
 Keyboard.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
 Keyboard.SendKeys(EntClient,this.selectParams.EntClientSendKeysEnter, ModifierKeys.None);
```

None of the above has pressed the enter key in the application.

Comment: Before sending the keys, are you focused on some input element?  You can probably use Coded UI to find the element and perform a click to give it focus before sending keys.

Comment: Firstly I'm typing a text, this works fine, after that I need to press Return key. I f I`m writing text I think the focus is in the right side.

Comment: Yep, I was just clarifying.  Maybe update, "When my test presses a key" to "After correctly sending in text, the enter is not being sent".  Are you setting the text with .Text property or Keyboard.SendKeys?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send keyboard or mouse input to a Citrix application running in Receiver you must send the input to the window with Window Class `CtxICADisp`:

[image]